# How To Find data by passing List of IMongoQuery

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-mvc-5, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

Below is my code where i am passing List showing no error during building solution but during run time its showing error.

```
An Array value cannot be written to the root level of a BSON document.
```

My Code Is :

```
public IQueryable<Folder> GetFolderByIdList(List<IMongoQuery> GraphIdList)
        {
            if (ApplicationDbContext.ServerIsDown) return null;
            _FolderList.Clear();
            if (!GraphIdList.Any())
            {
                return null;
            }
            var FolderData = db.Folder.Find(GraphIdList.ToBsonDocument()).ToList();
            if (FolderData.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (Folder item in FolderData)
                {
                    _FolderList.Add(item);
                }
            }
            var result = _FolderList.AsQueryable();
            return result;
        }
```

and below is my code what i have pass in GraphIdList

```
var UserFilesData = planetDriveObj.GetFilesOfFolder(
            Query.And(
              Query<UserFiles>.EQ(u => u.CreatorUserID, userInfoId), 
              Query<UserFiles>.Matches(u => u.Title, fileTitle)));

                foreach(var c in UserFilesData.ToList())
                {
                    idList.Add(Query.And(
                       Query<Graph>.EQ(u => u.GraphID, c.GraphID),
                       Query<Graph>.EQ(u => u.isHidden, true)));
                }

                var GraphData = GraphRepObj.getGraphDataBYIdList(idList);
```

Comment: could you show us what is `GraphIdList`?

Comment: @profesor79 yes i have editted Question please check it out